# Checking a URL in an if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, url, if-statement

I'm trying to check a submitted URL (excluding any additional paths).

The user submitted URL is:

```
var inputUrl = document.getElementById("inputVal").value;
```

If the user submits `'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'` then I'm trying to create an if/else statement that will determine whether the site is 'stackoverflow.com', regardless of `'http/https'` or any `'/.../.../'` after `.com`

```
if (inputUrl == "stackoverflow.com") {
console.log ("stackoverflow");
} else {
console.log("not stackoverflow");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Comment: `'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'  != 'stackoverflow.com'`. `==` compares the whole string for an exact match, not just partof it.

Comment: Exactly. I thought I remembered learning a trick where you could use an * to replace the variables i.e. '* stackoverflow.com *', but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if(inputUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf("stackoverflow.com") > -1) {
       ...
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

A little trick to have the browser do most stuff for you (can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)):

```
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';
console.log(url.host);      // stackoverflow.com


if (url.host == "stackoverflow.com") {
  console.log ("stackoverflow");
} else {
  console.log("not stackoverflow");
}
```

The same way you can also access other parts of the URL like protocol or hash.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. It works, however, there seems to be one small issue. `url.host` is coming out as `www.stackoverflow.com` not `stackoverflow.com`. This will cause issues in some scenarios. Do you have any idea how I could remove `www.`

Comment: @Jack The subdomain is part of the host as it can point towards a completely different site. I guess at that point you'll have to use String operations.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
var inputUrl = document.getElementById("inputVal").value;
    inputUrl=inputUrl.split("http://")[1] || inputUrl.split("https://")[1] ;
    inputUrl=inputUrl.split("/")[0];
    if (inputUrl == "stackoverflow.com") {
      console.log ("stackoverflow");
      } else {
      console.log("not stackoverflow");
      }

}) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputVal" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
<button>
submit
</button>
```

jsfiddle Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/geogeorge/h40dvbq6/2/